# Returning objects through Asynchronous calls in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am developing a **Pure Java program** that takes an **Address** in the form of **text** and the passes it to **Google Map API** for further breaking in  **Country,State and Zip**.

But I got stuck somewhere where my Java Program is throwing an exception resulting in awkward results.

Now I decided to use the java integrating it with Rhino.
This is because I successfully developed a Web Page that takes a string and parses it in **Country,State and Zip**.
So now my thinking is that I will integrate this JavaScript file in my Java file using Rhino.

```
           function showLocation(address) {
                var geocoder;
                if(!geocoder){
                    alert("GC is initialised");
                    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
                }

                geocoder.getLocations(address , function(response)
                     {
                        if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {alert("Sorry, unable to locate that address");}
                        else {
                          place = response.Placemark[0];
                        }
                     }//END OF CALLBACK METHOD
                );//END OF GETLOCATIONS
           }//end of showLocation
```

Now my question is that how can I return the object of **place** when I call **showLocations()**

Comment: You're using Javascript running in a Rhino Javascript interpreter embedded in a Java application because you had some problem with the Java application? Wouldn't it be better to solve your Java problem than to introduce *more* complexity?

Comment: You are 100% right @FrancisAvila but I tried almost everything that I kow but still that exception persists.So I changed the scenario and decided to use Rhino.

Comment: You should ask *that* question on StackOverflow. It doesn't seem that you have.

Comment: Ok @FrancisAvila I will definitely do that too,Thanks again for your great info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't!** Since `getLocations` is asynchronous, `showLocation` has already finished executing before `response` is available.

You need to accept a callback to `showLocation`. There are some other problems which I will fix below.

```
function showLocation(address, callback) {
    var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder(); // no need for !geocoder test--it will always be undefined!

    geocoder.getLocations(address , function(response) {
        if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
            alert("Sorry, unable to locate that address");
        } else {
            // you forgot the "var" before "place"--you were making a global variable "place"
            var place = response.Placemark[0];
            if (callback) callback(place);
        }
    });
}
```

Then you make the user supply a callback like so:

```
function placeCallback(place) {
    // do something with place object here
}
showLocation('my address', placeCallback);
```

Comment: So this means I can't return an object from this concept and use it with Rhino?

Comment: You can return anything you want from `showLocation()`, but you can't return something that doesn't exist yet!

Comment: So in case if I use your concept of **callBack** with `showLocation('myAddress',placeCallBack)`, how do I get the returned Object because I will call showLocation('ABC','placeCallBack') from my **JAVA** code and it in turns call **placeCallBack** which returns my Object
?

Comment: You should create a new question to answer that, because this gets in to your Rhino embedding environment which you don't describe at all. Looking at [the Rhino Embedding Tutorial](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/tutorial.html) it seems you have at least two options: expose the Java object that wants `place` to Javascript and invoke it in your `placeCallback`, or examine the scope object after evaluating your script.

Comment: However, I *really* think you should step back and evaluate why you are embedding a Javascript interpreter in the first place. Maybe you could solve your original Java exception problem and avoid the need for Rhino?

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrancisAvila I will reconsider my thought of getting into Rhino rather than solving the exception.Thanks a lot.